# I am getting the setspan error setspan starts before 0 at

Tags: java, spannablestring

I am getting the following error don't know what's wrong with my code. When its bold and italic then italic text sometimes removed and some time not and then get this error.

> 2018-11-10 19:34:03.032 16997-16997/com.pilum.apps.primalnotes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.pilum.apps.primalnotes, PID: 16997
>       java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: **setSpan (-1 ... -1) starts before 0**
>           at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1314)
>           at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:680)
>           at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:672)
>           at com.apps.primalnotes.Fragments.EditorFragment.italicText2(EditorFragment.java:393)
>           at com.apps.primalnotes.Fragments.EditorFragment.access$300(EditorFragment.java:48)
>           at com.apps.primalnotes.Fragments.EditorFragment$5.onClick(EditorFragment.java:129)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6877)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26069)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)

```
 private void italicText2(){
      boolean italicExists = false;
      Spannable str = texto.getText();
      int selStart = texto.getSelectionStart();
      int selEnd = texto.getSelectionEnd();
      StyleSpan[] styleSpans = texto.getText().getSpans(selStart, selEnd, StyleSpan.class);

      for (StyleSpan styleSpan : styleSpans) {

          int oldStyle = styleSpan.getStyle();
          int spanStart = str.getSpanStart(styleSpan);
          int spanEnd = str.getSpanEnd(styleSpan);

          if (spanStart < texto.getSelectionStart()) {
              str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(oldStyle), spanStart, selStart, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
          }

          if (spanEnd > texto.getSelectionEnd()) {
              str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(oldStyle), selEnd, spanEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
          }
          if (selEnd > selStart) {
              if (oldStyle == Typeface.ITALIC) {
                  str.removeSpan(styleSpan);
                  italicExists = true;
              }
              if (oldStyle == Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC) {
                  str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), spanStart, spanEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                  italicExists = false;
              }
          }

      }

      if (!italicExists) {
          Log.d("Tag", "italic section entered");
          if (styleSpans.length > 0) {
              int lastSpanEnd = 0;
              for (StyleSpan styleSpan : styleSpans) {
                  int oldStyle = styleSpan.getStyle();
                  int spanStart = str.getSpanStart(styleSpan);
                  int spanEnd = str.getSpanEnd(styleSpan);


                  if (spanStart > lastSpanEnd) {
                      str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), lastSpanEnd, spanStart, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                      Log.d("TAG", "if italic");
                  }

                  lastSpanEnd = spanEnd;
                  str.removeSpan(styleSpan);

                  if (oldStyle == Typeface.BOLD) {
                      str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC), spanStart, spanEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                      Log.d("TAG", "Bold and Italic");
                  }
                  else {
                      **str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), spanStart, spanEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);**
                      Log.d("TAG", "else italic");
                  }

                  if (spanStart < texto.getSelectionStart()) {
                      str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(oldStyle), spanStart, selStart, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                      Log.d("TAG", "oldstyle italic");
                  }

                  if (spanEnd > texto.getSelectionEnd()) {
                      str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(oldStyle), selEnd, spanEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                      Log.d("TAG", "old style end italic");
                  }
              }

              if (selEnd != lastSpanEnd) {
                  str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), selStart, selEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
              }
          }
```